# How to save a ExcelBook generated using ExcelTemplate on SharePoint2013 Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

```
wbook.SaveAs("c:\\temp\\blah", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
wbook.Close();
```

`wbook` is the object of the Workbook and trying to save it, but allowing only for local save location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the file a temporary location then upload that file to sharepoint using client object model.

```
  ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://spdevinwin");
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString(); 
foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray())
 passWord.AppendChar(c); 
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord); 
     Web web = context.Web;

       FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
     newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Work\Files\17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration.pptx");
      newFile.Url = "17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration 4MB file uploaded via client OM.pptx";

        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
      context.Load(uploadFile);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
```

After that you can delete that file from temp location.

Comment: After creating the the excel file with default template as Excel doc along with  populated data, i got an object of Excel.Worksheet , how can i perform above operation on that ..?

Comment: Can you save that file to your local disk ??

Comment: yes, using Excel.WorkSheet.SaveAs(destinationPath) method i can save that Doc to local machine.

Comment: So save that file to local disk then upload it to sharepoint document library.

Comment: i am trying to close the instance of excel using WorkSheet.Application.this Workbook.close(); Giving an issue " operation cannot be performed because it is used by another process ".

Comment: THis might be some excel issue. Don't have any idea about it.

Comment: issue resolved . Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);then Workbook.close(); now the file is successfully created , uploaded , converted into pdf(programatically) ,and saved.

Comment: So how are you uploading?

Comment: FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
     newFile.Content = **System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes**(@"C:\Work\Files\17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration.pptx");
      newFile.Url = "17580_FAST2010_S05_Administration 4MB file uploaded via client OM.pptx";

        List docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
      context.Load(uploadFile);
      context.ExecuteQuery();